# How many ways to visit 4 cities so that each city is visited exactly 4 times without visiting the same city twice in a row?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, generating-functions, hamiltonian-path

The inclusion-exclusion principle doesn't work.

Example of good path is:

$$ 1\to 2\to 1\to 4\to 3\to 2\to 1\to 4\to 3\to 
2\to 1\to 3\to 2\to 4\to 3\to 4$$

This one isn't:

$$ 1\to 2\to 1\to 1\to 3\to 2\to 1\to 4\to 3\to
2\to 4\to 3\to 2\to 4\to 3\to 4$$

because the $1$st city gets consecutive visits.

In graph theory the problem would be: How many paths are there in a simple undirected complete graph with $4$ vertices so that each vertex is visited exactly $4$ times.

Comment: Where did you meet this problem? Do you need to find a computation that can be carried out with pencil or paper, or would a strategy for computing the result on a computer also be acceptable?

Comment: For the computer option, dynamic programming would sound promising, but there are also only some 63 million paths _before_ the "not twice in a row" rule is applied. It may be faster just to iterate through all of them and count how many match, than it would be to program the more intricate dynamic programming solution.

Comment: In exam of discrete mathematics. A strategy for computing the result on a computer would be acceptable but I would like that algorithm solves the problem in polynomial time if is it possible (when you visit the city exactly n times), not the greedy algorithm.

Comment: x @ZDa: In polynomial time of what? Number of cities or number of visits to each or both?

Comment: Yes I know, I have wrote in the above comment "(when you visit the city exactly n times)". So I don't want the greedy algorithm that goes through all possible path and sees if is it good ( 16!/(4!*4!*4!*4!) possible paths ), I want to find the algorithm that could be generalized to solve the problem in polynomial time when you visit each city exactly n times.

Comment: x @ZDa: You're still not answering whether you consider the number of cities to be constant or a parameter you want the algorithm to be polynomial in.

Comment: First I would like to have the polynomial algorithm for fixed number of cities (each city visited exactly n times), because I didn't find that yet.
Here is a similar problem, n cities that have to be visited exactly twice (https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2013/08/28/permutations-of-1122-nn-with-no-two-adjacent-terms-equal/)

Answer (score 2):

After n visits to cities, we are in a state (a, b, c, d), where a is how often the last city was visited, and b, c, d is how often we visited the other cities. a+b+c+d will equal n. a, b, c, d are all 4 or less. We may assume that b, c, d are arranged  in descending order (for example 2, 3, 2, 0).

In the first move, there are four ways to enter state (1, 0, 0, 0). Then in every move, we can visit a city other than the last one visited which hasn't been visited yet. Combine the numbers how often identical states can be visited.

x cities visited at most y times works easily in y^x * y * x steps; polynomial for any fixed x.